# How to create custom php.ini file for zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio

I used PDO_MYSQL connection in application.ini file of zend its work on localhost because `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` is enable. When i run code on server its throws exception `Message: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'rdvscoin_main'@'host.indiandns.com' (using password: YES)` because `pdo_mysql` is disable on server and i want enable that extension by custom php.ini file. For this what can i do? I want to create custom php.ini file but i don't known how can i create , where its can store?
If any one have alternate idea then suggest me please.....

Comment: are you sure this is not a permission problem, `access denied`

Comment: yes..i validate all the things but you have some doubt plz say to me what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Zend, really.
There is no such thing as a custom php.ini for a single project. You can run VirtualHosts with different settings, but even they all use the same ini file i think.

Rather have the administrator enable PDO extension (but EVERYONE has that running Oo)

But given the error i'd say its a permission problem, too - tried using 'localhost' instead of the specified?